# Problem with {% url 'something:somthing' %}

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to make the url go as {% url 'namespace:name' %} but it don't work! I did everything according to the documentation, but all my attempts were in vain.

**My CartDetail.html**

```
..........
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="text-right">
    <button href="{% url 'shop:ProductList'%}" class="btn btn-info">Продолжить Шопинг</button>
    <button href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Оформить заказ</button>
  </p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**My shop/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    re_path(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ProductList, name='ProductListByCategory'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ProductDetail, name='ProductDetail'),
    re_path(r'^$', views.ProductList, name='ProductList'),

]
```

**And my main url.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static




urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^cart/', include(('cart.urls', 'cart'), namespace='cart')),
    path('',  include(('shop.urls', 'shop'), namespace='shop')),
 ]



if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

What should I to do

Comment: Do you receive any error messages?

Comment: @wencakisa this is the meaning of absolutely nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the docs:

```
path('publisher-polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='publisher-polls'))
```

from your code:

```
path('',  include(('shop.urls', 'shop'), namespace='shop'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In main `urls.py`

```
path('',  include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
```

In `shop/urls.py` add

```
app_name = 'shop'
```

Now, you can use,

```
"{% url 'shop:ProductList' %}" # spaces are necessary
```

Comment: it didn't fix the situation

Comment: Just nothing happens, no mistakes, nothing

Comment: console output: "{% url 'shop:ProductList' %}"

Comment: Django ver 2.2.3

Comment: Keep `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`, if it's not. check for the error! Without error it's hard to guess.